# Search for and replace text within text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have recently taken on a daily task, where an existing .bat file creates the required network folders when run everyday... as part of the task, I am looking at amending the contents of a text file as part of the initial setup i.e. running the .bat file.

Below is an extract of the .bat file, which has assigned the day, month and year as needed e.g. 11-03-2019, and creates the relevant folders the task needs, and copies across a control file (Filename2) to the newly created folder. What I'm looking to do is replace text within Filename2 in addition to having the folders created.

```sh
set vb=%temp%\newdate.vbs
echo Newdate = (Date()+0) > %vb%
echo Yyyy = DatePart("YYYY", Newdate) >> %vb%
echo   Mm = DatePart("M"   , Newdate) >> %vb%
echo   Dd = DatePart("D"   , Newdate) >> %vb%
echo   Wd = DatePart("WW"  , Newdate) >> %vb%
echo   Wn = DatePart("Y"   , Newdate) >> %vb%
echo   Ww = datepart("W"   , Newdate) >> %vb%

echo Wscript.Echo Yyyy^&" "^&Mm^&" "^&Dd^&" "^&Wd^&" "^&Ww^&" "^&Wn >> %vb%

FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims= " %%A in ('cscript //nologo %vb%') do (
        set Year=%%A
        set Month=%%B
        set Day=%%C
        set Week#=%%D
        set Weekday#=%%E
        set Day#=%%F
            )
del %vb%

for /f "Tokens=%Month%" %%A in (
  "January February March April May June July August September October November December") do (
  set Alfamonth=%%A
)

If %Month% lss 10 set Month=0%Month%
if %Day% lss 10 set Day=0%Day%
set Today=%Day%%Month%%Year%
set Tomorrow=%Today%+1


set Filename="path"
echo Source path\
echo filename = %Filename%
echo.
echo Today = %Today%
echo Year =  %Year%
echo Alpha month = %Alfamonth%
echo Day=%Day%
echo Month=%Month%

md %FileName%\%Year%\%Alfamonth%" "%Year%\Client\%Day%-%Month%-%Year%

::Copy CONTROL FILE

set Filename2="path\Client\Client.ini"
copy %Filename2% %FileName%\%Year%\%Alfamonth%" "%Year%\Client\%Day%-%Month%-%Year%\"Raw Data"\"%Day%%Month%%Year%.ini"
```

There are 2 lines on the control file that I'm looking to amend:

```
directory=/dataload/fulfill/data/Client_Feb2018/02022018/

filename=Client_01022018
```

For directory, I need to change `MonYYYY` and `DDMMYYYY` parts as follows every day e.g. `/dataload/fulfill/data/Client_Mar2019/11032019/`.
The filename line needs the same change e.g. `Client_01022018` to `Client_11032019`.
Given that `%Day%`, `%Month%` and `%Year%` have already been assigned, I'm hoping this will be an easy piece to add - any assistance is greatly appreciated!

p.s. I'm completely new to batch scripting.

Comment: So you want to change a date like `Client_Mar2019` to the corresponding long date? i.e `Client_11032019`?

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55102820/edit) to expand upon your script, so that we can clearly see at least all code which produces the following variables: `%Year%`, `Month%`, `%Alfamonth%` and `%Day%`? Thank you. _Please also note that there are several issues in just the portion of code you've posted, (hint: doublequotes), I would change all four of those lines currently posted!_

Comment: There are 2 changes needed for the directory line : Client_Feb2018 to Client_Mar2019, and 02022018 to today's date in DDMMYYYY format. So the line will change from : directory=/dataload/fulfill/data/Client_Feb2018/02022018/ to  directory=/dataload/fulfill/data/Client_Mar2019/11032019/